# "Partially correct" vs. "partial correct"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

> - It's partially correct.
> - It's partial correct.

Which of the following is grammatical?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is basic grammar: adverbs modify adjectives. I encourage you to visit and support the stackexchange site for [**English language learners**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). This is still under development and not yet accepting questions, but it will do so when interest reaches a critical mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Partially correct" is right; the other is not.